# node js sending json body in response

Tags: node.js

re-posting this question with different information.

I have 3 parameters.

```
  response.writeHead(200, 
        {       
         'Content-Type': 'text/json'            
        });      
      response.end({ID:'bufid',Name: bufname,address: bufaddrss});

    }
```

This is not working.
Here I want to send to the end user in 200 Ok a JSON Body as:

```
{'ID; :'123',
  'Name': 'alice',
   'address': 'xxxxx'}
```

Here bufid,bufname and bufaddrss are  values which are determined by functions and which can be accessible any where (they are global)

how can I send that information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to realize that the following:

```
{ID:'bufid',Name: bufname,address: bufaddrss}
```

is not JSON. JSON is a protocol. It is a string that encodes a javascript object with a syntax that is similar to javascript object literal syntax (hence the confusion and mix-up most people have with the term "JSON").

You first need to convert that object to JSON formatted string. Fortunately node comes with a built in method: `JSON.stringify()`.

```
response.end(
    JSON.stringify({ID: bufid,Name: bufname,address: bufaddrss})
);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply/. bufid,bufname and bufaddrss are values are variable values. I want the values of these variables to be printed not the variablenames. with what you suggested it prints bufid. but I want the value that is present in that bufid variable

Comment: its not printing the bufid and bufname , bufaddrsvalue together? if I do JSON.stringify({ID: bufid) - it works. but if I do JSON.stringify({ID: bufid,Name: bufname) it does not print..it just prints "ID":"","Name":""

Comment: It works. The bug you're having is most likely somewhere else. Here's a test: http://jsapp.us/#s360.js